# Going to people's house combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Many students in Mr. Noeth’s BC Calculus class missed their first test, and to avoid taking a makeup, have decided to never leave their houses again. As a result, Mr. Noeth decides that he will have to visit their houses to deliver the makeup tests. Conveniently, the 17 absent students in his class live in consecutive houses on the same street. Mr. Noeth chooses at least three of every four people in consecutive houses to take a makeup. How many ways can Mr. Noeth select students to take makeups?

I realized that every group of 4 consecutive students intersects with 3 of the next 4. This means that the next set can have all students already picked or one spot left.After that i have no clue what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he chooses the 17th student, then any acceptable set of choices of the first $16$ students remains acceptable. If he doesn't choose the 17th student, then he must choose the 16th, 15th, and 14th, but any acceptable choice of the first $13$ remains acceptable. So if $a_n$ is the number of ways to solve the $n$-student problem, then $a_{17}=a_{16}+a_{13}$. More generally, $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-4}$. Now if you can just work out $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$, you can use the recurrence to calculate $a_{17}$.